How to mitigate underbrace removing whitespace after the followup symbol
The underbrace and underbracket commands seems to remove the whitespace after follow up symbols.
In the following MWE the space between the + and c is too small:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  a = 
      c \cdot \left(\Delta t_{a g_i} - \Delta t_{a g_{tr}}\right)  
      + c \cdot \underbrace{\left( \delta_{g_i} - \delta_{g_{tr}} \right)}_{\mathclap{\text{Clock offset errors}}} 
      + c \cdot \underbrace{\left(\delta_{a g_i} - \delta_{a g_{tr}}\right)}_{\text{Other errors}} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}


It can be also reproduced with underbrace and also the mathclap doesn't seem to be the problem.
Only way I can think of is adding a \, between the second + and the c but I would still like to understand the underlying problem.
EDIT:
It also doesn't work in this simplified version without using mathtools
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  a = 
      c \cdot (\Delta t_{a g_i} - \Delta t_{a g_{tr}})  
      + c \cdot \underbrace{( \delta_{g_i} - \delta_{g_{tr}} )}_{\text{Clock offset errors}} 
      + c \cdot \underbrace{(\delta_{a g_i} - \delta_{a g_{tr}})}_{\text{Other errors}} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}




This is in the latex format, you don't need any package to show it. \underbrace is a \mathop so the following + is taken as a symbol following an operator and loses its infix spacing.
Wrapping the underbrace in {} makes them \mathord (or you could define a similar command that supplied the braces automatically).
\documentclass{scrbook}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  a = 
      c \cdot \left(\Delta t_{a g_i} - \Delta t_{a g_{tr}}\right)  
      + c \cdot \underbrace{\left( \delta_{g_i} - \delta_{g_{tr}} \right)}_{x}
      + c \cdot \underbrace{\left(\delta_{a g_i} - \delta_{a g_{tr}}\right)}_{x}
    \end{equation}


\begin{equation}
  a = 
      c \cdot \left(\Delta t_{a g_i} - \Delta t_{a g_{tr}}\right)  
      + c \cdot {\underbrace{\left( \delta_{g_i} - \delta_{g_{tr}} \right)}_{x}}
      + c \cdot {\underbrace{\left(\delta_{a g_i} - \delta_{a g_{tr}}\right)}_{x}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}

\end{document}


Thanks a lot. Never thought about it that way.

In several posts I have already suggested to define
\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}
\newcommand{\obrace}[2]{{\overbrace{#1}^{#2}}}

and you can supplement with
\newcommand{\ubrack}[2]{{\underbracket{#1}_{#2}}}
\newcommand{\obrack}[2]{{\overbracket{#1}^{#2}}}

Not only using \ubrace and friends solves the spacing issue, but also get rids of the weird syntax.
Full example (where I also got rid of all useless \left and \right):
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}
\newcommand{\obrace}[2]{{\overbrace{#1}^{#2}}}
\newcommand{\ubrack}[2]{{\underbracket{#1}_{#2}}}
\newcommand{\obrack}[2]{{\overbracket{#1}^{#2}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  a = 
      c \cdot (\Delta t_{a g_i} - \Delta t_{a g_{tr}})
      + c \cdot \ubrace{(\delta_{g_i} - \delta_{g_{tr}}t)}{\mathclap{\text{Clock offset errors}}} 
      + c \cdot \ubrace{(\delta_{a g_i} - \delta_{a g_{tr}})}{\text{Other errors}} 
\\[2ex]
  a = 
      c \cdot (\Delta t_{a g_i} - \Delta t_{a g_{tr}})
      + c \cdot \obrace{(\delta_{g_i} - \delta_{g_{tr}}t)}{\mathclap{\text{Clock offset errors}}} 
      + c \cdot \obrace{(\delta_{a g_i} - \delta_{a g_{tr}})}{\text{Other errors}} 
\\[4ex]
  a = 
      c \cdot (\Delta t_{a g_i} - \Delta t_{a g_{tr}})
      + c \cdot \ubrack{(\delta_{g_i} - \delta_{g_{tr}}t)}{\mathclap{\text{Clock offset errors}}} 
      + c \cdot \ubrack{(\delta_{a g_i} - \delta_{a g_{tr}})}{\text{Other errors}} 
\\[2ex]
  a = 
      c \cdot (\Delta t_{a g_i} - \Delta t_{a g_{tr}})
      + c \cdot \obrack{(\delta_{g_i} - \delta_{g_{tr}}t)}{\mathclap{\text{Clock offset errors}}} 
      + c \cdot \obrack{(\delta_{a g_i} - \delta_{a g_{tr}})}{\text{Other errors}} 
\end{gather}

\end{document}


The problem is that \underbrace and friends are realized as \mathop, which is simply wrong. Unfortunately Knuth decided that he liked a weird syntax…

Thanks. My search didn't match your suggestions.Marked the other answer as correct as it was earlier.

@qwertz As David would say, giving him the tick is a disaster!
